# How to limit the rounding of a Float Number to only its “Decimal Part” without affecting its “Whole Part”

Tags: javascript, floating-point, numbers, rounding, precision

I am unable to find any post on stackoverflow that asked or answered this question.

The normal rounding method rounds the “Float Number” as a whole (***i.e. both its fraction and whole parts are processed and impacted in the rounding process***).

So, normally (rounding up fractions):

```
   12.9768 Rounded to 3 decimal places is 12.977
           Rounded to 2 decimal places is 12.98
           Rounded to 1 decimal place  is 13.0     <== Whole part also changed
           Rounded to 0 decimal place  is 13       <== Whole part also changed
```

In the above examples, the whole part is also affected once the fractional part reached a whole number.

This is fine and convenient for almost all situations and is of course what is intended in any standard number rounding method.

However, what I am looking for is rounding (using javascript) of **only the fractional part of the number** (to the number of places specified) but **without affecting the Whole Part of the number**, so (the above examples would become):

```
   12.9768 Rounded to 3 decimal places is 12.977
           Rounded to 2 decimal places is 12.98
           Rounded to 1 decimal place  is 12.9
           Rounded to 0 decimal place  is 12
           Rounded to 7 decimal places is 12.9768000
```

In the above, the fractional part will be rounded up to whatever required decimal places **but the whole portion of the number will not be touched**.

Trailing zeros are required so the output format will be a String Type.

This process limits the rounding to the fractional portion of the float number with a limit cap/limit in that the rounding will not carry to the Whole Part; i.e. the maximum fraction will always be 0.999 etc.

A situation that uses this is that in a shop, the price tags need to be shown as USD NN.mm, but whatever the accounting system does as part of the calculations it cannot create a whole number. So if the original purchase price is USD 22.45, and rounding due to any calculations must not cause the USD 22 to become 23. So, it could be anything up to 22.99. This is an example where the fraction is 2 decimals (i.e. in US cents) but if the fraction is not 2, a generic and flexible solution is needed for rounding only the fractional part without touching the whole part.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following function... It basically cuts everything after the specified decimal place.

```js
function precission(n, count) {
  var indicator = Math.pow(10, count) || 1;

  return ((n * indicator) | 0) / indicator;
}
```

If you want trailing zeros just use string.padEnd(count, "0")

**Update:**

```js
var num = 12.9768;

function precission(n, count) {
  var indicator = Math.pow(10, count) || 1;
  var whole = n | 0;
  var decimal = n - whole;
  var rounded = Math.round(decimal * indicator) / indicator;

  return rounded >= 1 ? whole : whole + rounded;
}

console.log(precission(num, 0));
console.log(precission(num, 1)); //prints 12 because otherwise it would have been 13
console.log(precission(num, 2));
console.log(precission(num, 3));
console.log(precission(num, 6));
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks Tom. One issue is that it does not round correctly. for example `precission(1.987,2));` gives `1.98` it is supposed to be `1.99`. The function should do normal running up but not touch the whole part.

Comment: This seems to more complex than I thought

Comment: I think i just misunderstood something. You want a number to be rounded by convention but if you round the rounded number it should work like as if it was the original number? My method just cuts every decimal after a certain place, and that is what I believed is what you want. 
Maybe you need to store your original number somewhere to solve your problem. I hope I am right otherwise I am not sure what the problem really is.

Comment: It should do a normal round up of the decimal portion only but must not allow the rounding to go over and change the whole number. i.e. the whole part must remain intact. The decimal part must be rounded to the required decimal places as normal.

Answer (score 0):

To get the whole number as it is use

```
 Math.floor(12.9768)
```

It will give you the whole number which is expected to you, for fractional part fetch as it is or you can do like

```
Math.floor(12.9768) + ( 12.9768 - Math.floor(12.9768) )
```

Comment: When the number is negative, will this work?  Perhaps `Math.trunc()`?

Answer (score 0):

Having little javascript experience, I'll try a pseudocode/javascript solution:

```
function MA_Round(n, precision) {
  // break into whole and fractional parts
  var whole =  Math.trunc(n);
  var frac =  n - whole;

  // Round fraction
  var pow10 = Math.pow(10, precision);
  var rvalue = Math.round(frac*pow10)/pow10;

  // Form limit of highest fractional value and apply
  var limit = 1.0 - 1.0/pow10;
  if (Math.abs(rvalue) > limit) rvalue = limit;

  // Form result
  return whole + rvalue;
}
```

Comment: Yes. This gives me an idea to think about it. Thanks man.

Comment: As the output will require trailing zeros (i.e. a string output is needed anyway) one might start handling the whole number as a string from the outset.

Comment: @MohsenAlyafei The last part `whole + rvalue` may incur rounding up, so perhaps best to return those two values separately; printing the whole part and then the `rvalue` part.

Comment: @MohsenAlyafei In order to avoid rounding  troubles of the conversion of the FP value to a _string_, which in itself incurs a rounding, be sure to print to a string with at least 17, maybe 18 _significant_ digits.  Be sure to try any code you make with the FP value just less than 1.0, like 0.999999999999999

Answer (score 0):

This flow diagram could be **one way** to solve it:

[image]